# Best setup for Multi-Warehouse Stock per store level? MAGENTO 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, inventory

we are updated our site to have two store levels/ website (1.oceania - 2.Europe).
We use the same SKU but have different inventory.

What is the best way to set up this store?
Oceania Warehouse links to Oceania site only
Europe Warehouse links to Europe site only.

1. **Duplicate products** and change SKU (OC-00000 / ER-00000)
2. Host two different **Magento site and geoIP** customers to the right site

the issue is we use this **extensions appjetty (biztech) inventory** that doesn't have store level inventory.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use store-based inventory

Try this extensions: https://github.com/DemacMedia/Magento-Multi-Location-Inventory

That extension do what you want without any hacks